# How to get murmur (mumble server) on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I currently have a murmur server running on a separate host that I am hoping to get rid of, I was curious if anyone knew of murmur running on Heroku or something similar like dotcloud? If it is possible, how exactly do I get it running?

Comment: Run it on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible on Heroku - it's a closed platform. I would imagine the same for DotCloud too.